# How can I return an array of objects from an async function to a pug template?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise, pug

```
const Entry = mongoose.model('daily',entrySchema)

async function displayEntry(){
    let data = await Entry.find()
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

module.exports = { displayEntry : displayEntry }
```

// when I import displayEntry into a new document and try to display the data on a pug document I get [object promise]. I'm guessing I'm forgetting a step within the displayEntry function?

Comment: No, `displayEntry` is fine, it returns a promise, as expected. Please show us the part of your code where you import and call `displayEntry`, that's where you forgot a step (waiting for the promise to fulfill).

Comment: const entry = require('./entry.js')

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        entries: entry.displayEntry()
    })
    res.end()
})

sorry about the formatting it reads kinda weird but thank you for your help!

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include the code there with proper formatting.

Comment: The correct way would be `entry.displayEntry().then(data => { res.render('index', {entries:data}); res.end(); });`

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you so much @Bergi